After renaming my device all browsers stopped working
I use Ubuntu 22.4 LTS on my device and had the idea, to shorten the name of my device which I did. After renaming my pc all browsers stopped working. However, I am connected to the internet as emails, Skype, etc. are working fine.
To fix the issue, I went back to the old name with no result. I checked my DNS settings but they look just fine. I am not sure but it feels to me that it must be related to the user profile or hostname. However, I am not an expert (yet) ;-)
Any ideas, on how to fix it? I use tabs in bulk. Hence, a new installation would be my very last exit ... Thanks.

Delete your browser profiles, they will be recreated when you start them

Hi thanks for your feedback. I am still not sure what to do and where to find the profiles. I did use Midnight Commander but couldn't locate the profiles. I just hope, that I can keep my tabs and didn't expect that changing a device name has such an impact.

I was able to resolve my issue after I found the browser profiles in snap. I checked if the profiles are locked by using the command find -iname SingletonLock and deleting the profiles with rm ./snap/430/ ./config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/SingletonLock - I had two entries and deleted them both and finally access to Brave again (incl. all tabs etc.). For Vivaldi it worked similar. Of course one need to replace the profile number (430) with the own profile number.
